# Friedmann equations and the age of the universe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, relativity, cosmological-constant

We have Friedmann equations of the form
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{a'}{a}\right)^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho + \frac{\Lambda}{3}.
\end{equation}
We also assume that the stress-energy tensor has $T^{00} = \rho$ with all other components zero, so that $\rho \sim 1/a^3$ by conservation of energy. Assuming that the cosmological constant is small $|\Lambda| \ll 3H_0^2$, I've been asked to show that the age of the universe is given by:
\begin{equation}
\tau_0 = \frac{2}{3H_0}\left[ 1+\frac{\Lambda}{9H_0^2} + \mathcal{O}\left( \frac{\Lambda^2}{H_0^4} \right)  \right].
\end{equation}
So far I haven't had much success. I assume the approach is to rewrite the Friedmann equations as:
$$
\frac{1}{a'} = \frac{1}{a} \left( \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho + \frac{\Lambda}{3}\right)^{-1/2 }
$$
and then have:
$$
\tau_0 = \int\frac{1}{a} \left( \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho + \frac{\Lambda}{3}\right)^{-1/2 }da
$$
with which I can do some kind of expansion. I just don't know how to get rid of $\rho$ properly or plug in $H_0$ in a natural way. Also I'm a bit unclear about which limits I should be using for the integration. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: You haven't actually used the fact $\rho \sim a^{-3}$ anywhere. Maybe that will help?